# Cannot display contents of table in ListView

Tags: android, listview, android-sqlite, tablelayout, listactivity

I have an SQLite database which contains a table. I want to display the contents of the table using ListActivity and ListView. The problem is it only displays this

```
database.VesproModel@41814440
```

The VesproModel.java Class just holds the fields of the table along with their getters and setters.
I am able to successfully insert the data into the table which I have verified by pulling the database from the device and viewing it on the computer.

This is how I am dealing with fetching the data :

```
public List<VesproModel> getAllComments() {
    List<VesproModel> comments = new ArrayList<VesproModel>();

    Cursor cursor = database.query(MySQLiteHelper.TABLE_TPCS_VESSEL, allColumns, null, null, null, null, null);
    cursor.moveToFirst();
    while (!cursor.isAfterLast()) {
      VesproModel comment = cursorToComment(cursor);
      comments.add(comment);
      cursor.moveToNext();
    }
    cursor.close();
    return comments;
  }

private VesproModel cursorToComment(Cursor cursor) {
    VesproModel comment = new VesproModel();
    Log.d("cursorToComment", "Before if cursorToComment");
    if( cursor != null && cursor.moveToFirst() ){
        Log.d("cursorToComment", "inside cursorToComment");
        comment.setId(cursor.getLong(0));
        comment.setImo_number(cursor.getString(1));
        ...
        ...
        ...}
        return comment;
        }
```

And I am calling this function in a ListActivity like so :

```
public class CurrentList extends ListActivity {
private VesproDataSource datasource;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.currentlist);

    datasource = new VesproDataSource(this);
    datasource.open();

    List<VesproModel> values = datasource.getAllComments();

    ArrayAdapter<VesproModel> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<VesproModel>(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, values);
    setListAdapter(adapter);
     } 
   }
```

And this is the corresponding layout for the above ListActivity :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="match_parent"
     android:orientation="vertical" >

 <ListView 
    android:id="@android:id/list"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    >
</ListView>
</LinearLayout>
```

How can I display the data in the table on the screen. Please suggest what type of layout I should use as there are quite a few columns in the table. Thanks.

**EDIT 1 :**

As suggested , I made a custom class extending the ArrayAdapter class to handle displaying Vespromodel variables:

```
public class ItemAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<VesproModel> {
private List<VesproModel> objects;
public ItemAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId, List<VesproModel> objects) {
    super(context, textViewResourceId, objects);
    this.objects = objects;
}
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent){
    View v = convertView;
    if (v == null) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item, null);
    }
    if (i != null) {
            // I inserted some textviews to test the data out. For the final display , I would need many more textviews or a TableLayout
        TextView tt = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.toptext);
        TextView ttd = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.toptextdata);
        TextView mt = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.middletext);
        TextView mtd = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.middletextdata);
        TextView bt = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.bottomtext);
        TextView btd = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.desctext);
        if (tt != null){
            tt.setText("Imo_number: ");
        }
        if (ttd != null){
            ttd.setText(i.getImo_number());
        }
        if (mt != null){
            mt.setText("Vessel Name : ");
        }
        if (mtd != null){
            mtd.setText(i.getVessel_name());
        }
        if (bt != null){
            bt.setText("Vessel_type : ");
        }
        if (btd != null){
            btd.setText(i.getVessel_type());
        }
    }
    return v;
}
```

}

I am calling this from the ListActivity like so :

```
            List<VesproModel> values = dsrc.getAllComments();  // function is defined in the above section.
    m_adapter = new ItemAdapter(this, R.layout.list_item, values);
    setListAdapter(m_adapter);
```

Now the activity is getting stuck in an infinite loop inside the getAllComments() method.

Answer (score 2):

`ListView` doesn't know how to display values from `VesproModel`, that's why it displays the name of `VesproModel` class. What you want is to implement your own adapter that will know how to fetch data from objects of your class.

Or if `VesproModel` class has for example field that you want to display - let's call it `text` - you can use `ArrayAdapter<String>` instead of `ArrayAdapter<VesproModel>`, and then:

```
List<VesproModel> values = datasource.getAllComments();
ArrayList<String> valuesToDisplay = new ArrayList<String>();
for(VesproModel vm : values) {
    valuesToDisplay.add(vm.text);
}

ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<VesproModel>(this,
        android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, valuesToDisplay);
setListAdapter(adapter);
```

This way you have list of strings and `ArrayAdapter` knows exactly how to display those strings.

If you need more information, tell me, so I'll give more clear explanation.

Answer (score 1):

The `ResourceId` you are using in the `ArrayAdapter` accepts only Strings, so the values object must be a `Arraylist` of type Strings only.

Now, you need to create an Adapter that extends `ArrayAdapter<VesproModel>`, and then create your own row to display the comments in the `getView` method of the `ArrayAdapter`.

After you have created the Adapter,
you can call it by saying.

```
 MyAdapter<VesproModel> adapter = new MyAdapter<VesproModel>(this,
            R.layout.your_layout, values);
```

where `values = new ArrayList<VesproModel>;`

Answer (score 0):

Moquitos answer is correct. Another approach is to Override `toString()` method in your custom class `VesproModel`. Then instead of getting `database.VesproModel@41814440` it will print whatever you put in `toString()`. For instance, following Mosquitos approach, you could do something like this:

```
@Override
public String toString(){
    return text;
}
```

Comment: Didn't quite get you. Who is this "Moquitos" you are referring to ?

Comment: I meant Piotr Chojnacki. Lol :P

Comment: Override toString() method in your VesproModel class. And whatever you put in your toString() method will be written in your adapter, without having to create a custom adapter.

Comment: Yeah I was trying to override the toString() method. But the problem is that I have a mix of string and integer variables in the VesproModel Class. How can I override the toString method to incorporate this ?

Comment: mix of string? Im guessing you have a method for retrieving those strings in your class. What method would you be using in order to get those string?

Comment: In the VesproModel class I have these variables :                 private long id;
private String imo_number;
private String vessel_name;
private String vessel_type;  and their getters and setters.

Comment: What do you want to write? I mean, if it just a simple_list_item_1 for your adapter, then you can only write a String. So if you could in toString() put something like: return vessel_name + " " + vessel_type;

Comment: toString() is just a description of your custom class, that's all! you can put whatever string you want!

Comment: So by returning  vessel_name + " " + vessel_type + .. etc , I'll be able to display the list without the need for a custom ArrayAdapter ?

Comment: The ArrayAdapter is now looking for your toString() method, since you didn't override this, it is printing the address instead.